# Django messages not showing after redirect

Tags: python, django

I have this piece of code in my view:

```
if _user.objects.user_exists(_email):
    auth.logout(request)
    messages.success(request, 'You already hold a verified account with us. Please login.')
    return redirect('accounts:login')
```

and this in my template:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div>{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This sadly wouldn't work. But if I change `return redirect('accounts:login')` to `return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')`, the message would display. So what is it that's preventing the messages from showing up during a redirect?

And for the message storage, I am using:

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Suspect there is an issue with the session being deleted when you log out. Does it work if you use a different message storage backend?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried removing the logout call. It's still the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the issue after two days of hitting the wall. It was the session settings of my site.

```
# Session settings
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.mydomain.com'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

So this was obviously not picking up my session when developed on local (127.0.0.1), and since the local environment wasn't secure, the cookie was not being set as well.

To address this, had to take the following steps:

1. Add a host entry for `127.0.0.1 local.mydomain.com` in the development machine
2. Then modify the `runserver` command to `runserver local.mydomain.com:8000`
3. Finally, modify the secure cookie settings to `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = not DEBUG`

From then I had to access the local version with `http://local.mydomain.com:8000`.

Hope this helps anyone going through the same issue.

Comment: Why would this behave differently for render() vs. redirect()?

Comment: @sureshvv Since `render()` is being called in the same view that sets the message, the variable is seen as populated. Rather than a page called by `redirect()` has to rely on storage to get the message values.

Comment: But if properly set in session, both should work equally well, no?

Comment: unless SessionStorage is thread local, and another worker thread does not see it